# read tensor file via gcloud dataproc

Tags: tensorflow, pyspark, rdd, argparse, google-cloud-dataproc

hello how i should modify my code to read dataset2 properly ?

```
 %%writefile read_rdd.py 
def read_RDD(argv):
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() # get a parser object
  parser.add_argument('--test_set', metavar='test_set', type =ParallelMapDataset) 
  args = parser.parse_args(argv) # read the value
  args.test_set.take(3) 
  for i in args.test_set:
    print(i)
```

and to execute

```
test_set = dataset2     #dataset2 cannot be inserted
!gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster $CLUSTER --region $REGION \
    ./read_rdd.py \
    --  --test_set $test_set 

                                                                                                                                  aditional information
```

type(dataset2)  = tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops

i tried to change type =ParallelMapDataset to  type=argparse.FileType('r') but it didnt work as well

currently i cannot submit job 
im getting insted

/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 0:`gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster bigdatapart2-cluster --region us-central1     ./read_rdd.py     --  --test_set '

Comment: test_set <ParallelMapDataset shapes: ((192, 192, None), ()), types: (tf.float32, tf.string)>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please notice that the arguments you pass via `gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark` are translated to a standrad command line. Try to wrap the argument with quotes:

```
test_set = dataset2     #dataset2 cannot be inserted
!gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster $CLUSTER --region $REGION \
    ./read_rdd.py \
    --  --test_set "$test_set"
```

Comment: Thanks that work well but    when i try to make filetype as rdd  using  sc = pyspark.SparkContext.getOrCreate()
  test_set_rdd= sc.parallelize(args.test_set)  im getting TypeError: 'FileType' object is not iterable or when i do argv.test_set.batch(s).take(n) im getting AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'test_set' how to make test _set as readable rdd then ?